# onCreate got invoked onClick of the imageview in android

Tags: android

I have ScreenRecorder activity invoking RecorderService. RecorderService setting floating view with imageview. when i onclick on image view ScreenRecorder oncreate got called not able to invoke onclick action. But OnTouchListener working fine

```
      <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sr_float_home"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/recorder"
    android:onClick="startRecord"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
```

ScreenRecorder activity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate " );
     mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager)
            getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        recordeScreen();
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate end");
}
private void recordeScreen() {
    Log.d(TAG, "recordeScreen open " );
    if (mMediaProjection == null) {
        startService(new Intent(ScreenRecorder.this, RecorderService.class));
        finish();
        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "recordeScreen open end " );
}

 public void startRecord(){
 Log.d(TAG, "startRecord start " );
 startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(),
         PERMISSION_CODE_SR);
 Log.d(TAG, "startRecord end " );
 finish();
 return;}
```

RecorderService

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mChatHeadView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_screen_recorder, null);
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mChatHeadView, params);
    final ImageView srFloatHome = (ImageView) 
    mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.sr_float_home);
    srFloatHome.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        }
        }
        }
```

i have also tried placing startRecord method like ontouch , but still not working. can someone please tell me why onclick call not received insteated it calling activity oncreate.

Comment: have you tried adding click listener via code ?

Comment: yes, tried but not working.

Comment: If I understood your code, the problem is that you're finishing the activity when you invoke RecorderService, so the component is not binded with the ScreenRecorder activity and therefore, it doesn't find the startRecord function.

Comment: As said in the answer below, in order to call a method from onClick xml attribute, the method should have View as a parameter. So your method should look like this. `public void startRecord(View view).`

Comment: @gbelisario your answer was correct. Why did you deleted ?

Comment: @VivekMishra after reading the code more carefully, I thought the problem could be something else (just mentioned it above), but I undeleted the answer anyway ;)

Comment: Problem is indeed with the view parameter missing from the method call

Comment: @VivekMishra  i have tried like this   public void startRecord(View v){  but still oncreate get called

Comment: can you show your logs value

Comment: I have tired    srFloatHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG,"start record");
            }
        });   form  RecorderService

Comment: @VivekMishra onclick on image my activity got invoked 
10-17 10:13:52.177 1775-1998/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.yuga.simplified.screenshare/com.yuga.simplified.screen.recorder.ScreenRecorder} from uid 10058 on display 0
10-17 10:13:52.188 4000-4000/com.yuga.simplified.screenshare D/ScreenRecorder: onCreate 
10-17 10:13:52.189 4000-4000/com.yuga.simplified.screenshare D/ScreenRecorder: recordeScreen open

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-floating-widget-tutorial/. Try the steps from the tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're missing the parameter on your startRecord function. From Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#onClick):

> public static final int onClick
>
> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity)

Comment: for static i am facing issue but i have tried with public  final int startRecord(View v){ but not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code less a property in xml.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

if you want ImageView have the clicked method ,should add this,
this is demo code .xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:onClick="StartDoSomething"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

and in .java is

```
public void ButtonClick(View v){
    System.out.println("Do something here!");
}
```

hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used layout root element and used below code i am able to get onclick in recorderervices

```
 mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.sr_float_home);
```

form

```
    final View srFloatHome =  mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.sr_head_root);

    srFloatHome.setOnClickListener(this);
```

my onclick method in RecorderService

```
 public void startRecord(View v){}
```